# Route any to single endpoint and a specific to another?

Tags: node.js

I want to route all the requests to a particular endpoint except one, which will go to another endpoint. For example:

```
//I cannot use express
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const reqUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    if (reqUrl.pathname == '*' && req.method === 'GET') { //route all to this one
        // process
        res.end();
    }
    if (reqUrl.pathname == '/specific' && req.method === 'GET') { //unless the user types in /specific
        //process
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your specific route first, then put your general route:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const reqUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (reqUrl.pathname == '/specific' && req.method === 'GET') { //unless the user types in /specific
    //process
    res.end();
  }
  else { //route all to this one
    // process
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: why is else part hitting twice?

Comment: If you are testing your server with browser, I think the browser send an `option` request to your server for CORS.